# Using material icons with md-icon in Angular Material 2

Tags: css, typescript, angular, material-design, angular-material2

I cannot get md-icon to display the icons from Google Material. For those who don't need much exposition here is the code, more details are after the code.

app.component(where I display all of my main components, the actual md-icon is in header.component):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './shared/content.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<div id="wrapper">
    <header></header>
    <content></content>
    <footer></footer>
  <div>`,
     directives: [HeaderComponent, ContentComponent, FooterComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Header component (where I try to call md-icon):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MdIcon} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    template: `<md-icon>home</md-icon>
    <h1>This is the Header</h1>
    `,
    directives: [MdIcon]
})
export class HeaderComponent { }
```

and here is the css and html according to the steps on google materials site for using their icons:

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot");
  /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local("Material Icons"), local("MaterialIcons-Regular"), url("../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Boiler Plate</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/layout.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
  <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('app').catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->

<body>
  <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

Originally I was not getting any errors it was simply rendering the md-icon as "home" in plain text. However I think I was missing the directive for MdIcon, so I inserted that and now I recieve this error "No provider for MdIconRegistry!". They talk a little bit about the MdIconRegistry in their [docs](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components/icon) but from the way I am reading it you only need that if you don't want to use the standard google icons, which I do want to use. So basically I imported the component, included the directive, added the link in my index, and added the css code to my stylesheets. From what I have read it should work but I am clearly missing something.

Any help would be appreciated and if anyone has any critiques on the code unrelated to the actual question please feel free to let me know, I am very new to Angular 2 and I could use all the advice I can get.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I found what I was missing, it was in the docs, I just wasn't looking in the right place. Inside of your main.ts file you need to import and bootstrap HTTP_Providers and inside of your component you need to import MdIcon and MdIconRegistry as well as include the provider for MdIconRegistry. What does all of that mean? I am glad you asked!

Main.ts before:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Main.ts after:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

header.component.ts before:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MdIcon} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    template: `<md-icon>home</md-icon>`,
    directives: [MdIcon]
})
export class HeaderComponent { }
```

header.component.ts after:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MdIcon, MdIconRegistry} from '@angular2-material/icon';

@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    template: `<md-icon>home</md-icon>`,
    directives: [MdIcon],
    providers: [MdIconRegistry]
})
export class HeaderComponent { }
```

The documentation for the icons can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components/icon) and the documentation that helped me can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) at the very bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer here: You have to setup project properly. You are not importing the icons in the right way. You have to do nothing but import the icons and the fonts.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

You import this in the html and nothing else. Everything you did was a weird workaround.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon):

```
<!--
For Material Design Icons
The class '.material-icons' is auto-added if a style has NOT been specified
since `material-icons` is the default fontset. So your markup:
-->
<md-icon> face </md-icon>
<!-- becomes this at runtime: -->
<md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> face </md-icon>
<!-- If the fontset does not support ligature names, then we need to use the ligature unicode.-->
<md-icon>  </md-icon>
<!-- The class '.material-icons' must be manually added if other styles are also specified-->
<md-icon class="material-icons md-light md-48"> face </md-icon>
```

Comment: The documentation is from Angular Material 1, the problem is for Angular material 2, that's my fault though I tagged it as both angular-material2 AND angular-material. I am going to remove the angular-material tag, sorry for the confusion. (I did try your suggestion just in case though, no luck)